# Prove that from every infinite bounded series , there can be selected an convergent sub-series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that from every infinite bounded series , there can be selected an convergent sub-series.
This is the last question in the set of questions concerning series and sequences, it does not have an answer, and I do not know how to go about solving it.

Comment: So, you need to show the sequence of partial sums has a convergent subsequence...

Comment: How can a series be infinite and bounded at the same time? What is bounded? The series' terms?

Comment: Bounded as, there exists an $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|a_n|<M, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: If the original series is divergent and its terms $a_n$ are bounded then the statement is not true (just consider the case $a_k=1$). If the original series is convergent then it trivially satisfies the statement. Can you clarify your qiestion?

Comment: Can we assume that the terms of the sequence tend to 0? Because only so we can prove your statement.

Comment: I presume the problem is "suppose $\sum a_n$ is divergent, but the partial sums are bounded ..."

Comment: It is unclear what the hypotheses are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t \in \Bbb{R}$ and let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a bounded sequence whose series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i$ does not converge but whose terms tend to $0$. That is, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = 0$. We show that there is a subseries of $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ that converges to $t$.

Let $S_n$ denote the partial series $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$. Because $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is unbounded, for every $T \in \Bbb{R}$ there exists a $k$ such that $S_k \ge T$. We now construct the sub-series $\{b_n\}_{i=1}^\infty$ that converges to $t$ as follows:

Let $k_0$ be the first $k$ such that $S_{k} \ge t$ happens. Let us call $t_0$ to $S_{k_0}$.

Then we set $b_i$ to be equal to $a_i$ up to $k_0$. The elements of $b_i$ that are already set sum up to a total of $t_0 < t$ therefore the remaining elements we add **cannot** sum up to more than $t - t_0$ otherwise the sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i > t$. So we do just that:

Starting from $k = k_0$, we look for a term $a_k$ such that $a_k < t - t_0$. Let that term be $a_{k_1}$. We set the next term of $\{b_n\}_{i=1}^\infty$ to $a_{k_1}$, and then we update the total sum of the terms already defined in $\{b_n\}_{i=1}^\infty$ and call it $t_1$. Now we repeat the process: starting from $a_{k_1}$ we look for a term $a_{k_2} < t - t_1$. If we keep doing this, we see that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i = t$ since the partial sums converge to $t$.